# Is there any way to use the "out" argument of a Numpy function when modifying an array in place?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I want to get the dot product of two arrays, I can get a performance boost by specifying an array to store the output in instead of creating a new array (if I am performing this operation many times)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]])
b = np.array([[2.0,2.0],[2.0,2.0]])
out = np.empty([2,2])

np.dot(a,b, out = out)
```

Is there any way I can take advantage of this feature if I need to modify an array in place? For instance, if I want:

```
out = np.array([[3.0,3.0],[3.0,3.0]])
out *= np.dot(a,b)
```

Comment: Play with expressions like `np.multiply(np.dot(a,b,out),out,out)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Sadly that does not give the correct output (performing the `np.dot` overwrites the original values of `out`, which need to be used to get the correct answer)

Comment: Did you try: `np.multiply(np.dot(a,b),out,out)`, or `np.multiply(np.dot(a,b,out), out, out1)`.  I wrote 'play', not 'follow exactly'.  I'm suggesting something to explore.  I may not have hit on the exact combination of `outs`.

Comment: @hpaulj The second one would work, but I want to know if there is a way to do this without creating a second array to store output in. The first one loses the performance increase because `np.dot` is creating a new array.

Comment: Can you make the case that it is even logically possible?  `dot` has to store its result someplace, and it can't perform the extra multiplication itself.

Comment: @hpaulj No, I don't know that it's possible or impossible, that's why I'm asking. I'll accept "it's not possible" as an answer if it's well-justified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `out` argument to modify an array (e.g. `array=np.ones(10)`) in-place, e.g. `np.multiply(array, 3, out=array)`.

You can even use in-place operator syntax, e.g. `array *= 2`.

To confirm if the array was updated in-place, you can check the memory address `array.ctypes.data` before and after the modification.